# Why background drawable retain its state after activity finished?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-savedstate

I have a custom ViewGroup, It does only one thing, changing background's alpha on layout phase:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        ...
        getBackground().setAlpha(0);
        ...
}
```

print alpha in `setBackground`:

```
@Override
public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
    if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {           
        bgAlpha = Color.alpha(((ColorDrawable) background).getColor());
        d("bg:" + Integer.toHexString(bgAlpha));
        super.setBackground(background);
    } else {
       ...
    }
}
```

Now I have a activity inflate this custom view from layout xml:

```
   <CustomViewGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#88000000" />
```

When I first launch the app, `setBackground` print:

```
bg:88
```

then I finish the app and reopen it from launcher, `setBackground` print:

```
bg:0
```

Why background drawable retain its state after activity finished?